# Port Number Being Repeated Twice?

Tags: php

I have a small bug in the construction of my URL, I've setup a test for when I am not using `port:80` and for some reason if I use say `port:8080` it is applying the port number `twice` for some reason in the code cant explain it.

```
public function get_full_url()
{
    /** get $_SERVER **/
    $server = self::get('SERVER');

    $page_url = 'http';
    if(isset($server['HTTPS']) and $server['HTTPS'] == 'on')
    {
        $page_url .= 's';
    }

    $site_domain = (isset($server['HTTP_HOST']) and trim($server['HTTP_HOST']) != '') ? $server['HTTP_HOST'] : $server['SERVER_NAME'];

    $page_url .= '://';
    if($server['SERVER_PORT'] != '80')
    {
        $page_url .= $site_domain.':'.$server['SERVER_PORT'].$server['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    else
    {
        $page_url .= $site_domain.$server['REQUEST_URI'];
    }

    return $page_url;
}
```

Comment: so you're defining `example.com:8080:8080`? done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($server)` to see if the port's already embedded in one or more of the sub-values?

Comment: I have traced it in the source and the debugger i no its to do with request uri but cant figure it out

Comment: `print_r($server);` would pretty much do it...

Comment: Improved spellings and grammar

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` would contain port number as it is set in the `Host:` header